# Remove Multiple Periods Up To Bracket From String

Tags: regex, emacs

Would like to know how to create an Emacs macro that will

1. Find the first instance of multiple periods in string
2. Set mark
3. Move to the first closed bracket in string
4. Remove all chars between mark and closed bracket

Here is an example string. I'd like to go from this:

`* [This is Chapter 1.......................................................... 1-83](chapter1.md)`

To this: 
`* [This is Chapter 1](chapter1.md)`

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Try `M-x query-replace-regexp` with `\.\.+ [^]]*` (replace with empty string). Not sure about hpw many backslashes there should be.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the hacky way I accomplished. I'm sure there is a cleaner way.

1. Start with cursor at the beg of line
2. `M-x start-kbd-macro`
3. `C-s RET ..` to search for first instance of ".." in the string
4. `C-SPACE` to set mark
5. `C-s ]` to search for first instance of "]" in the string
6. `DEL` to remove everything marked
7. `BKSP BKSP` to remove the final two ".."
8. `DWN ARROW` to get to next line
9. `C-a` to get to beg of line
10. `M-x end-kbd-macro`

I know its lame, but it worked!! I have ~100 pages of docs to do this to! Need to figure out how to reliably perform this on the entire doc next.